# Python files don't recognize IDLE

Tags: python-2.7, python-idle

I had both Python 2.6 and 2.7 installed on my system and IDLE that I used (by right clicking on a Python file and selecting 'edit with IDLE') was from version 2.6. For some reason, I had to completely remove Python 2.6 form my system. Now, Python files don't show 'edit with IDLE' on right click, even though IDLE 2.7 is installed. I have also tried uninstalling Python 2.7 completely and re installing it. What could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me too once. 
Install Python. Then open IDLE and save an empty file with a `.py` extension. Then close IDLE. Go to the file that you have just saved. Then right click >> open with >> choose default program. Then choose `python`. There will be some more options like `pythonw` but you only choose `python`. After you are done, right click on the file and you will find "Edit with IDLE"
So, that is it.

Comment: No, not working for me. When you say 'choose python', you mean python.exe, right? The only change that this had made for me is that the icon of python files have changed from a small blank page to a page with python logo on it.

Comment: Yes, I meant the same. It worked for me. Let me look for some other way then. Will, you please tell me which location are you saving your `python` file in?

Comment: I saved the file on my Desktop and have also tried the suggested procedure by saving it in Python27 folder.

Comment: Meanwhile I did some experiments and I noticed: (i) If I saved a python file on desktop by the name (let's say) hello and selected the file type as `py` or `pyw`, the file would be saved without any logo or any default program. (ii) Then I saved another file (let's say) hello_2 but this time like this: `hello_2.py`, and this time, the logo appeared and when I did the right click on it, I got the option to "Edit with IDLE". Try it. Maybe it would help. :-/

Comment: @Babbage - was this ever solved? I am having the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to go right click on the file then choose look another app on PC and go C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib and choose the idle (batch file for windows)